# 2013 CSOM development-accessing List directly as user doesn't have permission to access teamsite

Tags: 2013, development, client-object-model, csom

I want to perform CRUD to a list from a console app or Asp .NET website. I am granted access to the list, but not the team site:
accessing this `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/teamname/a/b/Lists/Listname/Calendar.aspx` works, but this `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/teamname/a/b/` doesn't

I tried this code but I get UnauthorizedAccess exception. Is there a way to access the List directly using CSOM?

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(@"https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/teamname/a/b/"))
{
      SecureString pw = new SecureString();
      foreach(char c in "mypw")
      {
          pw.AppendChar(c);
      }
      clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myname@mycompany.com", pw);

      SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Listname");

      CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
      camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
      ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

      clientContext.Load(collListItem);

      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

      foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1} \nBody: {2}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"], oListItem["Body"]);
       }
 }
```